# Very slow boot time for Dell Precision laptop

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I just bought a very pricy Dell Precision (running win7). I am attaching the order confirmation that I got when I finalized the order online. In particular note the SSD hard drive.

[image: contract1]
[image: contract2]

Reason why I m opening this post is that this machine takes a very long time to boot: around 30 seconds from when I turn it on to when I get asked for my windows password. This seems VERY long to me. My 8y old crapy laptop (still win7) boots in around 35 seconds!! Apart from this, the machine looks fine.

I can be fine with the long booting time, but this leaves me wondering whether there are some inherent problems with the machine..

I cannot attach a screenshot from "System Information" b/c I need 10 reputation points, but it says

**Model SK hynix SC300 2.5 SCSI Disk Device.**

The letters SSD never appear there...

My questions are:

- does the hard drive in "System Information" match what I was promised on the contract? Is it possible that they just put the wrong hard drive on my machine?
- How do I check more generally if the performance of my machine is acceptable?
- Is there maybe a simple way to make my machine boot much fatser?

Thanks a lot in advace!!

Giulio

Comment: It's not like all vendors would put the letters "SSD" into the model field in the ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE data...also a simple google can tell you [what the heck is that drive](http://ssd.skhynix.com/ssd/en/about/std.jsp).

Comment: Install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx also works for win7),run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start.This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: Thx a lot magicandre! When trying to do that I get a warning from WPR saying: "The paging executive is enabled on this system, which can lead to incomplete stacks in traces. ...". Is it safe to mess up with the registry? What should i do?

Comment: this setting is fine. Apply it. Also notifiy me about your reply with @ myusername

Comment: @magicandre1981. Sorry what do you mean by "apply it". Should I disregard the warning and go ahead or change that variable in the registry?

Comment: change the value in the registry or run **wpr.exe -disablepagingexecutive on**. It is already set to 1 since Windows 8

Comment: have you captured now a boot trace after setting the value? Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thx a lot for your help. I ll do shortly.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need for the term SSD to appear in the name of the product. Similar to how a "volvo 360" is not called "automobile volve 360", yet it still is a car.

So, no need to panic or suspect that you got something else than ordered.

Googling on your bolded name i find lots of hits for SSDs. It appears that this name is used for a range of three MLC SSD's with 128 / 256 / 512GB capacity. So yes, it is a SSD.

As to boot times. Wow, 30 seconds is FAST. If you expected a lower time then you will need to figure out how long it takes to do parts of the boot process. E.g. POST might take a minute and actual windows loading another minute. (Actual times measure on my i7 desktop). If POST is long then check things like boot order (is it trying to PXE boot, then boot from ODD< then from a main drive. And timingout each time before it starts to boot?). Or is windows starting lots of needless services (iTunes, 'helpful dell gadgets', etc etc when it powers up?)... But that is the subject for a whole new post.

As for this one: Yes, it is an SSD. You did get what you paid for.

Comment: Somewhat conforting! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 7 boots up around 30 seconds, then I would say your machine is working fine. As you can check online that several Windows 7 user requires 40-43 seconds to boot up their machine. So comparing to them, yours is working fine.

It doesn't matter if your SSD does not appears their as different vendor has different name and model name for every cards.

To make your PC faster, you can follow this link: http://www.pcworld.com/article/244020/how_to_make_your_windows_pc_boot_faster.html